# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4, 1000]

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

Here is the code for the data pre-processing and the model training. Here some of the functions required for the model are not given.

```py
import argparse
import os
import time
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
my_df = pd.read_csv('data/array.csv')
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
# Drop the column with the header "Geometry"
my_df = my_df.drop(columns="Geometry")

# Save the modified DataFrame to a new CSV file
my_df.to_csv('tf_converted_dataset.csv', index=False, header=False)
# Define data types for TensorFlow conversion
data_types = [tf.int32 if str(dtype) != 'float64' else tf.float64 for dtype in my_df.dtypes]

# Load the CSV file as a TensorFlow CsvDataset
csvData = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset('tf_converted_dataset.csv', data_types, header=False)

# Get the column names
col_names = list(my_df)
col_names_ = col_names[:4] + col_names[4:1005]


# Define the parse_csv_row function
def parse_csv_row(*vals):
    feature_vals = vals[:4]
    features = dict(zip(col_names_[:4], feature_vals))
    targets_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(vals[4:1004])
    return features, targets_tensor

# Map the parsing function to the dataset and batch the data
dataset = csvData.map(parse_csv_row).batch(1000)

# Print an example batch from the dataset
for batch in dataset.take(1):
    features, targets_tensor = batch
    print(batch)

def get_data(features, targets_tensor, percenttest=.2, random_state=42):
    train_x = features
    print(train_x)
    train_y = targets_tensor
    print(train_y)

    x_train, test_x, y_train, test_y = train_test_split(train_x, train_y, test_size=percenttest,
                                                        random_state=random_state)
    x_test, x_val, y_test, y_val = train_test_split(test_x, test_y, test_size=.2, random_state=random_state)
    return x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, x_val, y_val
#After this the model of the neural network starts
```

The data set has geometrical combinations(input features of four columns) and radar cross-section(RCS) responses in the frequency domain for each geometrical combination(from column 4 to column 1004 with the column head of the respective frequency point). From the preprocessing, I created input features of the following shapes:

```
- 'la': tf.Tensor: shape=(1000,), dtype=float64, numpy=array
- 'lb': tf.Tensor: shape=(1000,), dtype=float64, numpy=array
- 'l1': tf.Tensor: shape=(1000,), dtype=float64, numpy=array
- 'w': tf.Tensor: shape=(1000,), dtype=float64, numpy=array
- tf.Tensor: shape=(1000, 1000), dtype=float64, numpy=array
```

I created the model and preprocessed the data but when I tried to feed the data into the model I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\basnaym1\GitHub\deepa_learining_Neural_N\python_based\elc_core_1_nn.py", line 262, in <module>
    main(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\basnaym1\GitHub\deepa_learining_Neural_N\python_based\elc_core_1_nn.py", line 124, in main
    train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y, val_x, val_y = get_data(features, targets_tensor, percenttest=0.2, random_state=42)
  File "C:\Users\basnaym1\GitHub\deepa_learining_Neural_N\python_based\elc_core_1_nn.py", line 113, in get_data
    x_train, test_x, y_train, test_y = train_test_split(train_x, train_y, test_size=percenttest,
  File "C:\Users\basnaym1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_param_validation.py", line 214, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\basnaym1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 2646, in train_test_split
    arrays = indexable(*arrays)
  File "C:\Users\basnaym1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 453, in indexable
    check_consistent_length(*result)
  File "C:\Users\basnaym1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 407, in check_consistent_length
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4, 1000] with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4, 1000]
```